# Touch events in UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, uitouch

I'm making a painting application in iOS . I'll give a brief outline of the logic here ,

1.Initialize a bitmap
2.Whenever a touchBegan or touchMoved event is detected , I draw a filled CGRect at that position on the bitmap and the bitmap is drawn to screen.

It works perfectly except for a little problem . If I move the mouse in the simulator really fast I dont get a continuous stroke . Its just a series of disconnected CGRects . I did some research which showed that in iOS touch events are fired only every 16 milliseconds but I dont think I'm moving the mouse that fast . So is the problem with the simulator or my code ?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{    

       CGPoint touchPoint=[touch locationInView:self];

       CGContextFillRect (currentBitmap, CGRectMake (touchPoint.x -8 , touchPoint.y - 8   , rectangularBrushSize, rectangularBrushSize ));

       [self setNeedsDisplay]; //draw currentBitmap to screen

}
```

The code for touchesMoved is the same . The draw rect method draws currentBitmap to the screen .I'd like to add once more that it works perfectly when I move the mouse with medium speed.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use `CGContextMoveToPoint` and `CGContextAddLineToPoint` to make a drawing app.Otherwise your line will not looks smooth.

*I wrote an app in this way, and didn't have the problem you got.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. There's probably nothing wrong with your code or the simulator. Instead of drawing rectangles at the current mouse/finger position, you have to remember (in an instance variable) the last position and connect it with the current one with a line.

In `touchesBegan`:

```
lastPosition = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
```

In `touchesMoved`:

```
currentPosition = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPosition);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPosition);
// Draw the line with the desired color and width here.
lastPosition = currentPosition;
```

Comment: I think you're right but Could you please clarify as to why this is the case ? I was under the impression that when we touch and drag the touchEvents would be triggered for every point in between and hence we would always get a continuous stroke.

Comment: connecting the points with a curve would give a more natural result no ? Drawing the curve/line after the points are detected would introduce a delay right ?

Comment: That's technically not possible. In the world of computers you (almost) always have a discrete representation of the real world. In this case, the touch screen only registers interaction every few milliseconds. It can't guess for you which pixels you touched between those points.

Comment: Yes, a curve might be a better choice, but also a lot more difficult to implement. I don't see where there would be any delay in the above implementation. You could draw a dot/rectangle in `touchesBegan:` too if you want.